# Is it safe to use my oven with no light bulb in it at all?

Tags: appliances, oven

I looked in the oven before sticking a pizza in it and noticed the bulb was popped so I carefully removed it and now I don't know if it's safe to use the oven with no bulb.

It's a Roper oven, and the bulb just sticks out with no cover.

Comment: is the bulb broken, dangling or just burnt out?

Answer (score 4):

Never leave a live empty socket unless it is behind a guard for safety reasons. It would be better to leave the old bulb in. Big box has replacements last time mine went out. Couple of bucks. Then at least you can check the progress of your pizzas.

Comment: Good advice, even if he's sure that he'll never reach that far back into the oven while cooking, when it comes time to clean the oven and he's in there with a wet sponge, he may end up with a nasty (and potentially dangerous) shock.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get it back into the slot (Unplug the oven first).

I've had bulbs burn out in ovens and not gotten around to replacing them for months. Never had an issue with the ovens performance or safety.